# How to add dependency in webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

If I use `require` to import a module the error is: `webpack_require is not a function`.

If I use the `import statement` then its function are not working and I get a `type-error`.

Does webpack not work with bower?

Comment: You could resolve dependency using an alias. Refer https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/?_sm_au_=iVV36JHHfHv4frZr#resolvealias

Comment: If I am using **angular.min.js** and that need jquery dependency then how will I add that  in webpack.

Comment: I have added an answer below explaining the details. If that works for you, consider upvoting and accepting the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could resolve dependency using an alias. Refer https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/?_sm_au_=iVV0dsf3NTdNVrRc#resolvealias

In webpack add the following config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      jQuery: path.resolve('./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'),
      ...
    }
  }
```

In the application wherever you need `jQuery` import using below line (assuming you are using `CommonJS` module):

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

Hope this helps :)